# Empty array in c++ shows absurd behavior

Tags: c++

The code:

```
int arr[] = {};
int n;
n = 7;
arr[0] = 15;
cout << n;
```

gives output:`15`

Why not `7` ?

Comment: it is giving 7.

Comment: Depends of your compiler, e.g. https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler outputs 7

Comment: Not only depends on the compiler, it depends on the settings you used when you compiled the application.  There is no guarantee what will be printed if you do things like this.

Comment: Also, the code [fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/349a2230c2357507)

Comment: @80sax technically those are more correct , because a) C++ doesn't permit zero-sized objects, in late standards a base-class subobjects are allowed to be zero-sized;   b) writing to n like that would be obviously a boundary breach and strict aliasing breach. But in any case allowing such declaration is a C-like extension to standard.

Comment: @kofhearts check this screenshot: https://ibb.co/ygJ77Yc
It does show 15, else I wouldn't have posted this issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just used gcc compiler which is most probably the most famous compiler out there (atleast for beginners).

Comment: @TonyStark *I wouldn't have posted this issue.* -- Undefined behavior.  Don't know how much more clear to put it.  Second, the default settings for g++ allows non-standard C++ programs to compile.  Use the correct settings, and that code fails to compile.  Also, Visual C++ is also popular, maybe more so, than g++ for beginners.  The code will also fail to compile with Visual C++, and no settings are available to accept such code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Instead of just saying it depends on my compiler and the settings, you could have given some constructive recommendations to avoid such mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line in your code creates an array of size `0`.

The next variable in the memory is `n`, and that's why your program overrides it.

You need to fix your first line to:

```
int arr[1] = {};
```

Like people mentioned in the comments above, it does in fact depend on your compiler.

Comment: Perhaps it would be appropriate to add that the C++ standard does not allow for empty arrays, so we have a compiler extention here.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explaination  !  And now I am going to switch my compiler which follows the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do dynamic arrays like that in C++, the size needs to be known at compilation and cannot change dynamically for native arrays, instead use std::vector.

```
#include<vector>

std::vector<int> arr; 
arr.push_back(15);
...
```

alt.

```
#include<vector>

std::vector<int> arr{15};
```

Comment: While I agree with what you say, it does not answer the question which is: `The code gives output:15 Why not 7?`

Comment: Because it is undefined behavior